# Finding the values of $Q$ from $180^{\circ}$ to $360^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have $\cos{Q}=-0.5$, required to find $180^{\circ}\leq Q\leq 360^{\circ}$.

What I tried: The acute angle is $60^{\circ}$, then, since cosine is negative on third quadrant, I suppose the value is $180^{\circ}+60^{\circ}=240^{\circ}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But grownups use radians.

Comment: Correct and well deduced.

Comment: I encourage you to answer your own question, and accept the answer. Some here like to keep the number of listed 'unanswered questions' low.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  There are two values within a circle that have a given cosine (except -1,0,1).  For $\cos Q=0.5$, these are $150^\circ$ and $240^\circ$ and you have found the right one.